# Where can I find J/XFS SDK for download?

Tags: java, sdk, xfs

I need to develop a XFS SPI for a device that will run over J/XFS standard. I already developed a SPI for XFS as a DLL written in C, but now I need to do it in Java.

I tried over and over to find any source for this standardization with no avail. As per my research, I understand it was discontinued. I couldn't find anything related in CENELEC sites.

Does anyone know about how I can find this?

Thank you

Comment: Hi people! I have the same problem... And I realy need some information about how we can get the J/XFS manager library. I need to implement a printer system to thermal printers in some banks institutions from Brazil. But the "Caixa Econômica Federal do Brasil" bank still uses legacy systems based on J/XFS requests. So, how we can find the libraries and tester software related to J/XFS?